# Prevent Caching in Windows FTP (Explorer)

Tags: windows-7, ftp, cache

Windows Explorer's FTP functionality appears to be caching downloaded files, such that when I drag drop (to download) the same file again, it's not downloading the latest version from the FTP server. How can I disable file caching in Explorer's FTP support?

Comment: Did you try just clearing the browser cache ?

Comment: @Psycogeek I can't do this every time. I need a way for the FTP cache to be disabled indefinitely.

Comment: I figured that, but does clearing it work? there can be 3 sides to a cache. the original server, the ISP cache, and your own. the first 2 are usually covered because of problems it caused people, any caching on thier end, is way more carefull.

Comment: @Psycogeek gotcha. Yea, I tried clearing IE's cache and that seems to clear the FTP cache. So at this point I'm hoping for a way to separate the two, and if not, a "plan B" is to disable IE's cache altogether I suppose.

Comment: does that "private browse" stuff use the cache less? Are you  Open to other software , like a downloader that bypasses windows cache?  A FTP client that actually uses all features of the FTP, instead of windows method?  A Ram_disk Cache for the net temps, that clears in miliseconds? Setting a cleaner to icon click, on command, like Ccleaner and a quick shortcut to it running one action with just one click, or a quick batch that ripps through temps?

Comment: The Explorer setting is not "disable cache", it is "enable cache checking". Although it applies to both http and ftp items, the action is to check the date/time on the remote item, rather than just trusting the expiry date of the local cached item. Also, to force a reload (when the item date/time has not changed), just reload the page/item, using "reset" or "F5", you don't have to clear the whole cache.

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me:

**Control Panel** =>
  Internet Options =>
    Browsing history :: [ **Settings** ]

Temporary Internet Files =>
  (+) *Every time I visit the webpage*

Click [**OK**].
If it sets back to *Automatically* => Ignore.

---

Cached files located here (Win 8.1):
 `C:\Users\ <name> \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache`
    or
`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no way that I know of to manipulate that. Is another FTP client (Filezilla for example) a viable option?

Comment: I would also use a ftp-client like filezilla. This behaviour of windows-ftp is really old and I don't think that it will be fixed.

Comment: 5 years and the problem remains :|